# Is it possible to bond 2 bonded interfaces?

Tags: networking, interface, network-bonding

It's actually the 1st time to bond on ubuntu.
And I made some configurations about /etc/network/interfaces but it's
not working ;

```
===============================================================
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

# The secondary network interfaces
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet manual
bond-master bond1

auto eth3
iface eth3 inet manual
bond-master bond1

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
    bond-mode 802.3ad
    bond-miimon 100 
    bond-slaves eth0 eth1
    bond-master bond2

auto bond1
iface bond1 inet static
    bond-mode 802.3ad
    bond-miimon 100 
    bond-slaves eth2 eth3
    bond-master bond2

auto bond2
    address 192.168.10.136
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.10.2
    bond-mode active-backup
    bond-miimon 100 
    bond-slaves bond0 bond1
dns-nameservers 168.126.63.1 168.126.63.2
===============================================================
```

Could you tell me the part of the wrong configuration, please?

Comment: Perhaps "#" at the front of the bold sentences are not working well and to get bold.

Comment: Why don't you add eth0, eth1, eth2 and eth3 to bond2 without bond0 and bond1? I am not sure it is possible to make bonding hierarchy as you did it.

Comment: It's because of dualized 4 switches which are connected with ubuntu server. I would like both to expand bandwidth and to make active-standby.

Comment: Let's say you add all eth to one bond to expand bandwidth. What happens if one eth fails. I guess it would work on remaining three eth connections. And if another one fails, it will work on remaining two. Is that not OK? And switches need to support bonding. Don't forget that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I dont think that is possible. The reason is you are trying to layer the same network layer on top on the first. Typically, you can tunnel L2 (ethernet) over tunneling protocols like L2TP or GRE etc. So you will have to create full L3 stacks on your bond0 and bond1 and layer a tunneling protocol on top of it to make them look like L2. At that point, you should be able to bond the two links.

You are best off with doing a bonding of all 4 interfaces into a single bond. That should give you the redundancy and high bandwidth without the complexity.